# Заполнение особого бинарного дерева в С++

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево

Собственно класс бинарного дерева я прописал (хоть и криво, не в этом дело).
Но метод вставки не подходит к поставленной задачи.
А именно:
На вход программы подается массив (например: 1 4 6 10 0 0 0 7...), где каждый ноль это листок-затычка после которого добавлять ничего нельзя, а все числа добавляются слева на право (сложно объяснить, на скрине пример)
[image: Пример массива и как он должен выглядеть в дереве]

Вот мой класс дерева:
h:

```
#pragma once
class binTree
{
    struct Node
    {
        int Value;
        Node * pLeft;
        Node * pRight;
        Node * pParent;
        Node(int x) :Value(x), pLeft(NULL), pRight(NULL), pParent(NULL) {}
    };
    Node * m_pRoot;
    void InoderTreeWalk(Node * x);
    Node * TreeSuccessor(Node *x);
    Node * TreeMin(Node * x);
public:
    binTree();
    ~binTree();
    void TreeInsert(int k);
    Node * TreeSearch(Node * X, int k);
    void ShowTree();
    int Root();
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "binTree.h"


binTree::binTree()
{
    m_pRoot = NULL;
    cout << " binTree::binTree() " << this << endl;
}


binTree::~binTree()
{
    cout << " binTree::~binTree() " << this << endl;
}


int binTree::Root()
{
    return m_pRoot->Value;
}

/*Нормальная функция вставки*/
void binTree::TreeInsert(int k)
{
    Node * z = new Node(k);
    Node * y = NULL;
    Node * x = m_pRoot;
    while (x != NULL)
    {
        y = x;
        if (z->Value < x->Value)
            x = x->pLeft;
        else
            x = x->pRight;
    }
    z->pParent = y;
    if (y == NULL)
        m_pRoot = z;
    else if (z->Value < y->Value)
        y->pLeft = z;
    else
        y->pRight = z;
}


binTree::Node * binTree::TreeSearch(binTree::Node * X, int k)
{
    if (X == NULL || k == X->Value)
        return X;
    if (k < X->Value)
        return TreeSearch(X->pLeft, k);
    else
        return TreeSearch(X->pRight, k);
}

void binTree::InoderTreeWalk(Node * x)
{
    if (x != NULL)
    {
        InoderTreeWalk(x->pLeft);
        cout << ' ' << x->Value;
        if (x->pParent != NULL)
            cout << " Parent = " << x->pParent->Value << endl;
        else
            cout << endl;

        InoderTreeWalk(x->pRight);
    }
}

binTree::Node * binTree::TreeSuccessor(Node * x) // поиск следующего элемента
{
    if (x->pRight != NULL)
        return TreeMin(x->pRight);
    Node * y = x->pParent;
    while (y != NULL && x == y->pRight)
    {
        x = y;
        y = y->pParent;
    }
    return y;
}

binTree::Node * binTree::TreeMin(Node * x)
{
    while (x->pLeft != NULL)
        x = x->pLeft;
    return x;
}


void binTree::ShowTree()
{
    cout << "\n Tree: \n";
    InoderTreeWalk(m_pRoot);
    cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Функция TreeInsert вставляет новые значения так, как это должно происходить в нормальном дереве поиска.

А мне **нужна функция которая будет вставлять новые элементы как показано в примере (как на скрине)**.

Comment: Слишком много букв?

Comment: Букв нормальное количество, но класс лишний, достаточно одной функции вставки

Comment: Покажите что сами сделали

Comment: Все сам сделал.

Comment: Ну так и ответьте на свой вопрос

Comment: @Cerbo забавный ответ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К стати эту задачу я решил  с помощью "топорного метода", но все же работает.

```
void binTree::AddNum(int x)
{
if (m_pCurrNode == m_pRoot && m_left == true)
{
        m_pRoot->pLeft = new Node(x);
        m_pCurrNode = m_pRoot->pLeft;
        m_pCurrNode->pParent = m_pRoot;
}
else
{
    if (m_left)
    {
        if (x)
        {
            m_pCurrNode->pLeft = new Node(x);
            Node * tmp = m_pCurrNode;
            m_pCurrNode = m_pCurrNode->pLeft;
            m_pCurrNode->pParent = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            m_left = false;
        }
    }
    else // to right
    {
        if (x)
        {
            m_pCurrNode->pRight = new Node(x);
            Node * tmp = m_pCurrNode;
            m_pCurrNode = m_pCurrNode->pRight;
            m_pCurrNode->pParent = tmp;
            m_left = true;
        }
        else
        {
            m_right = false;
            Node * pTMPstart = m_pCurrNode;
            m_pCurrNode = m_pCurrNode->pParent;
            // дойти до следующего узла по значению...
            if (m_pCurrNode->pRight == NULL)
            {
                m_right = true;
            }
            else if(m_pCurrNode->pRight != pTMPstart)
            {
                // если правая ветка не пустая
                m_pCurrNode = TreeMin(m_pCurrNode->pRight); 
                m_left = m_right = true;
            }
            else
            {
                while (m_pCurrNode->pRight == pTMPstart)
                {
                    pTMPstart = m_pCurrNode;
                    m_pCurrNode = m_pCurrNode->pParent;
                    if (m_pCurrNode == m_pRoot)
                        break;
                }
                m_right = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

п.с. спасибо за помощь=))))